# Write a python program to find sum of first and last digit of a number by using loop

Tags: python, new-operator

Hello I am new to coding and just learn some basics of codding can anyone help me out with this problem :- I have written a code to find 1st and last term using  loop but can't add them the code is given below

```py
n = input("enter your number:-")

#By loop 

if (n.isnumeric):
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if i == 0:
            print(f" your first digit of the number is {n[0]}")
        elif i== len(n)-1:
            print(f" your last digit of the number is {n[-1]}")
else:
    print("Please enter a number and try again!")
```

please can someone modify this code to find the sum of 1st and last digit ?
thank you:)

Comment: Do you have to use a loop?

Comment: Since you have already figured out first and last digits, all you need to do is print their sum; print(first_digit + last_digit)

Comment: if you use a loop and then get the last one using n[-1], it kind of defeat the purpose. so you can do n[0]+n[-1] or define variables first_n=n[i] and last_n=n[i] in your if, and then sum the first_n and last_n

Comment: If the input is, say, '9' is 9 both the first and last digit? Or should you be checking that the input is at least 2 characters?

Comment: What happens if the given input number is a single digit - eg. ```9```?

Comment: @blackbrandt yea my mam told me to use the loop function

Comment: @BikramjeetSingh i tried that one now i understand that i have to change it to int() first to add them otherwise i tried to add then in string and the output is useless ----> example(3214 output = 34)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're very CLose to the answer you're seeking, there are just a few errors to be corrected.  See the revised version, and check?

**Note** - this is to follow OP's thinking, and make minimum changes.
Of course, there're many alternative ways to achieve it (and more error checking for invalid inputs, but that's another *story/exercise).*

```py
n = input("enter your number:-")    # ex. 123 

#By loop 

if (n.isnumeric()):                # calling the method:  isnumeric()
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if i == 0:
            first = n[0]          # assign it to first digit
            print(f" your first digit of the number is {n[0]}")
        elif i == len(n)-1:
            last = n[len(n) -1]   # assign it to last digit
            print(f" your last digit of the number is {n[-1]}") # convert to integer

print(f' the sum of first and last digits: {int(first)+int(last)} ')
# 4      <- given input 123
```

Comment: or last = n[i], since he wants to use a loop...

Comment: Sure... that's for OP to continue the exercise. ;-)

Comment: It's better not to use ```range``` - just check the length of number and get the first/last in one shot.

Comment: if you don't loop, you can just do it un a one liner. I assume, further in the process more if conditions will be added, but can't be sure...

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to get the last item in a sequence - i.e., n[-1]

Therefore, using a loop is irrelevant.

What you do need to do however is to check 2 things.

1. Is the input at least 2 characters long?
2. Is the input comprised entirely of decimal characters

Which gives:

```
inval = input('Enter a number with at least 2 digits: ')

if len(inval) > 1 and inval.isdecimal():
    first = inval[0]
    last = inval[-1]
    print(f'Sum of first and last digits is {int(first)+int(last)}')
else:
    print('Input either too short or non-numeric')
```

Another interesting approach using *map()* and some unpacking to process the input:

```
inval = input('Enter a number with at least 2 digits: ')

if len(inval) > 1 and inval.isdecimal():
    first, *_, last = map(int, inval)
    print(f'Sum of first and last digits is {first+last}')
else:
    print('Input either too short or non-numeric')
```

Comment: `inval` reads closer to _invalid_ than _input value_